# Strange behavior with a link in my meteor app

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have something strange with a piece of code.
I have interventions and each intervention is associated to a customer. Then, in my interventions list template I use:
`{{pathFor 'editCustomer' customer}}` where customer is the customer _id.

If I print `{{customer}}` I get `vFJHY2CtLi4GC7T5h` but the link contains `ueYXhWGL6mG3Cbq3v`

`ueYXhWGL6mG3Cbq3v` corresponds to intervention _id

So the link is wrong beacause the id parameter is not that from the customer but the intervention

The document looks like:

```
{ "_id" : "ueYXhWGL6mG3Cbq3v", "title" : "intervention#1", "priority" : "medium", "customer" : "vFJHY2CtLi4GC7T5h", "assignedTo" : "97xzchCuSQGduz5vR", "issue" : "pokpokpok", "author" : "97xzchCuSQGduz5vR", "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-02-04T06:47:28.033Z") }
```

My router for customer id is:

```
Router.route('/customers/:_id', {
    name: 'editCustomer',
    data: function() { 
    return Customers.findOne(this.params._id); 
  }
});
```

An idea ?

Comment: Could you show how you generated that link? The SpaceBars code and helpers, to have a full [mcve].

Comment: you can try on http://test_pour_ccomb.meteor.com/interventions with these sources https://bitbucket.org/anybox/gestion-des-interventions

Comment: Could you include a [mcve] in the question itself rather than link to an external resource?

Comment: Maybe try: {{pathFor 'editCustomer' _id=customer}}

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
{{#with Customer}}
```

to set the data context just before

```
{{pathFor 'editCustomer' }}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to prefix the value with _id= like proposed by [Łukasz Kapica](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5769845/%C5%81ukasz-kapica)
So: `{{pathFor 'editCustomer' _id=customer}}`

Thanks [Łukasz Kapica](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5769845/%C5%81ukasz-kapica)